# How to deserialize an entire parent node inside an XML to a single string

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have an XML file which has nodes,
[image]

I need to deserialize it to the class

```
    [Serializable]
    public class MasterSettingsFile
    {
        public string version { get; set; }
        public bool IsEncrypted { get; set; }
        public string settingsString { get; set; }
        public string GetSettingsString()
        {
            if(IsEncrypted)
            {
               // return decrypted string
            }

            return settingsString;
        }
    }
```

I need to get the whole text under `<settingString>` as string

I tried normal deserialization. But gives error. Tried adding the whole node to "value" but still '<' causes problem.

Answer (score 0):

protected bool WriteConfigFile(string fileName, Type type, object obj)
        {
            bool retValue = true;

```
        FileStream fileStream = null;
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = null;

        try
        {
            this.BackupFile(fileName);

            fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);

            xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(type);

            xmlSerializer.Serialize(fileStream, obj);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            retValue = false;

            //LogManager.SingleInstance.WriteLog(this, ex.ToString());

        }
        finally
        {
            if (fileStream != null)
            {
                fileStream.Close();
            }

            if (retValue== false)
            {
                this.RestoreBackupFile(fileName);
            }

            this.DeleteBackupFile(fileName);
        }

        return retValue;
    }
```

The main issue was that the xml was not formed using Serialization. Once I did that, this deserialization worked fine. When serialized, it will automatically save using escape symbols.